# algorithm to get result like taxonomy_get_tree(). But retrieve only non empty terms

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

I need to get an associated array of terms in drupal that has node associated with it. However, I can't seem to figure it out the appropriate algorithm.

What I want is something like taxonomy_get_tree(). But, only term that has associated node with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will get the term ids for you.

```
db_query("SELECT DISTINCT tid FROM {term_node}");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do exactly what you're after.

```
$terms = array();
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {term_data} WHERE tid IN (SELECT DISTINCT(tid) FROM {term_node})");
while($term = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $terms[] = $term;
}
```